# How to do simple math operations in Java?

Tags: java, math, operators

For some reason, my math for the equation just isn't working. This is literally my first Java program, so go easy and don't use concepts and stuff I won't understand.

No matter what numbers I put in, the result always says: The first zero: NaN. The second zero: NaN. I'm not trying to code a program that will deal with unreal numbers. All the numbers I've inputted are always ones that will have real zeros.

Can someone help me with this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] num = new double [3];
        double answer1;
        double answer2;

        System.out.print("Enter A, B, C: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            num[i] = reader.nextDouble();
        }


        answer2 = (((num[1]*-1.0)-(Math.pow((Math.pow(num[1],2.0)-(num[0]*num[2]*4.0)),0.5)))/(num[0]*2.0));
        answer1 = (((num[1]*-1.0)+(Math.pow((Math.pow(num[1],2.0)-(num[0]*num[2]*4.0)),0.5)))/(num[0]*2.0));

        System.out.println("The first zero: " + answer1 + ".");
        System.out.println("The second zero: " + answer2 + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output for answer1/2 given 3 doubles (A, B, and C)? Also try breaking down the equation into smaller parts first and then work your way up to condensing it into a single lined equation

Comment: It works fine for the real zeros. I tried your code. Are you sure you've got the good examples? Try some textbook examples, they work.

Comment: If I enter `1 2 -3` it correctly answers `1.0 -3.0`. What inputs did you try and what output did you expect for that input? You do know that since you're dividing by `A`, answer will always be `NaN` if the first number is `0`, right?

Comment: *Coding hint:* Don't read the 3 values into an array. Use three variables named `a`, `b`, and `c`. Makes code much more readable. --- If you remove unnecessary parenthesis, code also becomes easier to read. --- `Math.pow(b, 2)` is the slow way to calculate `b * b`. --- `Math.sqrt(x)` is better than `Math.pow(x, 0.5)`. --- All in all, your formula would then become: `answer2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);`, which makes it actually look like the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) that it is.

Comment: ok yes all of you guys were right i thought what i was typing was right but it had no real zeros... lolz. anyway i have changed the variables to a,b,c and it is much easier to read. thanks for that, and i also got rid of a lot of the parenthesis. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Math.pow(-4.0, 0.5) = Math.sqrt(-4.0) both results in NaN
```

Make sure you provide input that does not give a negative value for
     Math.pow(num[1],2.0)-(num[0]*num[2]*4.0)

This would return valid result, for example
A=1, B=100, C=10

```
The first zero: -0.10010020050140156.
The second zero: -99.8998997994986.
```